# Definition of Normalizers in Algebraic Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an affine algebraic Group, $H \subseteq G$ a closed subgroup. The Normalizer of $H$ is usually defined as $\text{N}_G(H) := \{ g \in G | gHg^{-1} = H\}$.

However, some authors define it as $\text{Tran}_G(H,H) = \{g \in G | gH \subseteq H \}$

(for example Def. 4.14 in "Actions and Invariants of Algebraic Groups" by Santos, Rittatore).

How are these definitions equivalent?

Edit: The definition of Transporters involves a variety $X$ on which $G$ acts morphically. For subsets $Y, Y \subseteq X$ the transporter is then given by
$\text{Tran}_G(Y,Z) = \{g \in G | gY \subseteq Z \}$.

I suspected that G acts on itself via plain group multiplication so the definition makes sense for a subgroup $H \subset G$.

Comment: this can't be true since if g is not in H, g*H can't be a subset of H

Comment: I'm sure this is wrong for arbitrary groups. In the case of algebraic groups there seems to be an argument of inner automorphisms mapping closed subgroups onto closed subgroups of the same dimension. Unfortunately I don't understand how that helps.

Comment: Perhaps there's a typo and you mean $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$? Regardless of whether the group is algebraic, if $g\notin H$ then $gH$ is completely disjoint from $H$.

Comment: No the Definition is correct, just as in [the book](https://books.google.de/books?id=zf_9RdmJFwEC&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=definitions+of+transporter+algebraic+groups&source=bl&ots=AalMKlqNG9&sig=ACfU3U1c_EwC2FhUznUA4NwoNaDKidw-0g&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7wom5sKfpAhVB3KQKHQcrA5EQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=transporter&f=false), page 119

Comment: Well then $\mathrm{Tran}_G(H, H) =H$, not $N_G(H) $. The definitions are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of transporter you quote is

> Let $X$ be a $G$-variety. Let $Y, Z \subseteq X$, Then the transporter from $Y$ to $Z$ is $\{ g \in G : g \cdot Y \subseteq Z \}$

In this definition, $g \cdot Y$ refers to the action of $G$ on $X$ (and its subsets) which is implicit in the statement that $X$ is a $G$-variety, the action beging a map
\begin{align*}
&G \times X \to X\\
&(g, x) \mapsto g \cdot x
\end{align*}
I am using the notation $g \cdot x$ for the action of $g \in G$ on $x \in X$, to differentiate this from the product within $G$, which I denote by juxtaposition.

In this case, regard $G$ as a $G$-variety, the action being given by
$$
g \cdot x = g x g^{-1}
$$
for $g, x \in G$. (On the left side we have the action, on the right side a group product.) With this action, the transporter is nothing else but the normaliser.

Comment: Suspected as much (a dot missing). Thanks for the confirmation :-)

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear how the definition is equivalent. Is there any reason why G acts on itself via conjugation instead of plain group action?

Comment: @Finikow, there are many possible actions, you choose the one that fits with what you want to do.